# How send Chain Json with submit into a form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm new with programmation JQuery, Json into PHP.
my doubt is this:
I have a chain Json as the following example

```
[
 {"idwork":"1","status":"to_do"},
 {"idwork":"2","status":"in_process"},
 {"idwork":"3","status":"testing"}
]
```

and this chain is lodged in a variable called "data". I want post this to a class, named operation where it receive this values idwork and status, to do a consultation into SQL.

## Class operation

```html
<?php
require_once('../../clases/tarea.php');
$operacion=$_REQUEST['operaciones'];
$tarea_temporal=new tarea($_REQUEST['idtarea'],'','',0,0,0,0,0,$_REQUEST['status']);

switch($operacion)
{
case 'Modificar':
$tarea_temporal->update_status();
break;
}

header('Location:../baraja/task.php.php');
?>
```

I want to know how to send this variable in a form

Comment: `<blink>` tags kind of already tell "I'm new with programmation"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use json_decode, and then u can access the data like object or array... At doc u have an example:

https://www.php.net/json_decode

Comment: and something else. as can I  send the value of the variable "data" that contains the Json  into a form? to do a submit to class operation.